# linear programming - how to set variable to be 0 or 1?

Tags: java, linear-programming, integer-programming, apache-commons-math

I am trying to apply linear programming for my problem using Apache commons Math library. I saw an example online to solve the following example

```
max.  3X + 5Y 

 s.t.

 2X + 8Y <= 13 

 5X - Y <= 11 

 X >= 0, Y >= 0
```

The code is like

```
LinearObjectiveFunction f = new LinearObjectiveFunction(new double[] { 3, 5}, 0);

 Collection constraints = new ArrayList();
 constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 2, 8}, Relationship.LEQ, 13));
 constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 5, -1}, Relationship.LEQ, 11));

 constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 1, 0}, Relationship.GEQ, 0));
 constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[] { 0, 1}, Relationship.GEQ, 0));

 //create and run solver
 RealPointValuePair solution = null;
 try {
 solution = new SimplexSolver().optimize(f, constraints, GoalType.MAXIMIZE, false);
 }
 catch (OptimizationException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 if (solution != null) {
 //get solution
 double max = solution.getValue();
 System.out.println("Opt: " + max);

 //print decision variables
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 System.out.print(solution.getPoint()[i] + "\t");
 }
```

However, what if I want the value of X and Y can only be either 0 or 1? Is apache libs allow us do this? If no, any other libs I can use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... no. Not within the bounds of [*linear* programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). The reason is that in linear programming your constraints must be **linear**, and your solution space must be convex. The constraint of either 1 or 0 is not linear. The solution space {0, 1} in the real numbers is not convex (proof: the average of 0 and 1 is .5 and is not in the solution space).

The solver you're using in your code runs the [Simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm), a very popular linear program solver, but it really only solves pure linear programs.

To get either 0 or 1 you need [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), which is a little different. Basically, it's linear programming but with all (or some, in the case of mixed integer linear programming) values forced to be integers. The specifics are a bit out of scope for Stack Overflow (check out the [Math Stack Exchange!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming)); suffice it to say it's **not** linear programming but it **is** doable, and there are libraries that let you do it. There are even algorithms for it that are fairly easy to understand ([e.g. branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound)) albeit not a walk in the park to implement (they're generally the sorts of algorithms you want to let someone else implement, rather than roll your own).

If this makes you say *"I need an integer linear program solver!"* then you might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698304/how-to-perform-integer-linear-programming-in-apache-commons-math) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916428/integer-linear-programming-java-multiple-open-source-and-commercial-tools-are-a).

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the integer linear programming. By browsing the link you provided, I am thinking of using ojalgo lib. However, do you know where I can maybe find some examples or documents for how to use it (especially integer linear programming).

Comment: Hey - no, sorry. I haven't worked with any ILP libraries, so I'm no better at finding resources for one than you are. I do recommend, when you're figuring out what you want to use, checking whether the library has an active github/forum/stack overflow community that asks and answers questions about it. It'll make your life easier if you get stuck.

Comment: Go to https://www.ojalgo.org/code-examples/ and search for ExpressionsBasedModel.

Comment: @apete, I tried Ojalgo, it cannot handle the scale of my problem. I end up with GLPK, which needs some set up to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late but in case people are still considering this, before going to the Branch and Bound algorithm try using a cut generation algorithm to reduce further the number of nodes the first needs to explore (reducing time). Like the Gomory's cut, if you are implementing it, I think this one is easier to make. But anyway, first reduce the number of variables needed to explore before the the Branch and Bound specially if you are working with a big number of variables and constraints.

Comment: your answer is very informative, but lacks for some code example to be more illustrating